how to create a custom selector function in React Native that appends selected text to the clipboard
I need to append my email address after the copied content.
eg: Suppose i selected "Hello world" from Text component, so i want that the clipboard should have "Hello world Contact me: abc@gmail.com".
<Text
  key={Math.random()}
  selectable={true}
  selectionColor="orange"
  style={[
  styles.lyricsText,
     {
       fontSize: fontSizeCount,
       alignSelf: 'flex-end'
     },
   ]}>
    Hello world, I am using react native, and exploring features in react native clipboard.  
    </Text>



I have used the react-native-clipboard/clipboard and tried on add lister, but that won't work since it will fall in infinite loop to add the text.

The code i used for setting that additional text to clipboard is like

 const [clipBoardString, setClipBoardString] = useState('');
    const clipBoardStringRef = useRef('');
    const setIosClipBoard = useCallback(async (initialString) => {
        clipBoardStringRef.current = initialString.join(' ');
        clipBoardStringRef.current += ' Read more at shaivam.org';
        Clipboard.setStrings(clipBoardStringRef.current);
    });

    const setAndroidClipBoard = useCallback(async (initialString) => {
        clipBoardStringRef.current = initialString;
        clipBoardStringRef.current += ' Read more at shaivam.org';
        Clipboard.setString(clipBoardStringRef.current);
    }, []);

    const fetchClipBoardString = useCallback(async () => {
        return Platform.select({
            ios: Clipboard.getStrings(),
            android: Clipboard.getString(),
        });
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        Clipboard.addListener(() => {
            fetchClipBoardString().then((string) => {
                setClipBoardString((prev) => string);
            });
        });

        return () => Clipboard.removeAllListeners();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (clipBoardString) {
            Platform.select({
                ios: setIosClipBoard(clipBoardString),
                android: setAndroidClipBoard(clipBoardString),
            });
        }
    }, [clipBoardString]);

So,is there any approach or callback that i am missing to add in text through which i can achieve this.
